# Python Mocking framework for RabbitMQ

Tags: python, rabbitmq

We want to mock Rabbitmq calls from python for writing unit test cases.
Are there any fwks which provide this capability.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mocking the RabbitMQ server itself, you can mock the dependent service on the other side of the external RabbitMQ server. You can do this using an [async API simulation/mocking tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools).

For example you can use [Traffic Parrot](https://trafficparrot.com) which can be run in a Docker container as part of your CI/CD pipeline.

Here is a [video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFYJHa3j3uc) of how you can use the tool to send mock response messages to a RabbitMQ queue in an [aysnc request/response pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/rabbitmq-request-response). There is also a corresponding [tutorial available](https://trafficparrot.com/tutorials/service-virtualization-mocking-or-simulating-rabbitmq.html) to follow.

[image: Request/Response RabbitMQ pattern]
[image: Recording gRPC messages]
[image: Replaying gRPC messages]